# Как объявить один файл scss и использовать его во всех других файлах scss?

Tags: reactjs, scss

не где не могу найти , хочу создать два глобальных scss файла mixin и variables, объявить их один раз где-то и не писать во всех компонентах @import и путь к этому scss файлу , раньше писал на vue , я делал это в vue.config.js вот так

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '.',
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `
            @import "@/styles/_variables.scss";
            @import "@/styles/_base.scss";
            @import "@/styles/_mixin.scss";
          `
      }
    }
  }
}
```

создал файл webpack.config.js, установил npm install sass, написал в нем

```
module.exports = {
   module: {
     rules: [
       {
         test: /\.scss$/,
         use: [
           {
             loader: 'sass-loader',
             options: {
               includePaths: ['./src/style/variables.scss'],
               verbose: true,
             },
           },
         ],
       },
     ],
   },
 };
```

и ничего не подключается?